# How to use build-helper-maven-plugin to create extra directory?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e, build-helper-maven-plugin

I have a Java Maven project with the following structure. (This is a logical structure, not necessarily the exact directory structure.)

```
Project
|-Submodule
| |-src/main/java
| |-src/main/resources
| |-src/test/java
| |-src/test/resources
| `-pom.xml
`-pom.xml
```

In accordance with (my understanding of) Maven standards, the parent pom references the submodule in it's `<modules>` tag, and the submodule pom references the parent pom as it's `<parent>`.

Now, my goal is to use Maven to add two new source folders to the submodule, namely `src/integrationTest/java` and `src/integrationTest/resources`. I want Maven to "know about" these two folders so that I can execute the tests therein using my Maven testing plugin, `maven-pmd-plugin`. And I want Eclipse to "know about" these two folders so that they display correctly in Eclipse's graphical Project Explorer.

I was told that the `build-helper-maven-plugin` plugin could be used to create these additional directories that I needed. So I added the following configuration to my submodule pom:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>add-integration-test-sources</id>
                <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <sources>
                        <source>src/integration-test/java</source>
                    </sources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>add-integration-test-resources</id>
                <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/integration-test/resources</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

When I rebuilt the project, Maven didn't generate the directories I wanted. So I took the plugin configuration out of my submodule pom and put it in my parent pom instead. Maven still didn't generate my directories.

At this point, I don't know how to get this plugin working. I'm trying to follow other online tutorials, but I must be doing something wrong. Could anyone explain which pom file is intended to configure `build-helper-maven-plugin`? And how do I configure Eclipse to display the new Maven project structure correctly?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: For integration tests you should not create supplemental directories. You should use different naming schemas which already exists (like *IT.java) via the maven-failsafe-plugin. Apart from that you should not generate directories during the build outside `target` folder cause that will produce issues related to your version control....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[khmarbaise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296328/khmarbaise)'s comment made me realize my mistake, although I didn't take his advice.

The `build-helper-maven-plugin` configuration should go in the submodule pom (not the parent pom) where I originally had it. But Maven will not create these directories for you, *you* create the directories and then Maven uses them.

Once Maven is using your new directories, Eclipse displays them just fine.